# problems with data loading to train keras tensorflow model (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

problems with data loading to train keras tensorflow model (Python).

Good morning, I have the following problem:

I have a python program, in a first phase I indicate the directory of some images, the program processes the images and applies different filters for each processed image, it saves 4 different images in a different directory, with this in the destination folder I have 4 more times of images, up to here everything works correct.

Then I run a second pytjon script, what it does is read the images from the directory where there are more images and I order them in 4 arrays, each index of the array corresponds to the same image but with a different filter, for example image A is It decomposes into image A_1, image A_2, image A_3, image A_4, these images are in the same position within the 4 arrays.

Once with these 4 arrays I pass them to the fit function of my model, the problem I have is that with little training data (few images) the program correctly trains my model, but having many images fills the memory and ends the program unexpectedly.

My question is the following, how can I tell keras's fit () function to read the data as needed so as not to have it load everything into memory at once.

I use the following function to read the images:

```py
def leer_datos_Wavelet(path_imagenes_positivas_originales, path_imagenes_negativas_originales, path_imagenes_positivas_entrenamiento, path_imagenes_negativas_entrenamiento):
    
    # obtener archivos de imagen de datos de entrenamiento equilibrados y aumentados por clase
    positiveImageFiles = [f for f in listdir(path_imagenes_positivas_originales) if (isfile(join(path_imagenes_positivas_originales, f)))]
    negativeImageFiles = [f for f in listdir(path_imagenes_negativas_originales) if (isfile(join(path_imagenes_negativas_originales, f)))]

    
    contador_positivo = len(positiveImageFiles)*4
    contador_negativo = len(negativeImageFiles)*4

    print('ejemolos positivos: ' + str(contador_positivo))
    print('ejemplos negativos: ' + str(contador_negativo))
    contador_imagenes_totales = contador_positivo + contador_negativo
    #inicialización
    img1 = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, ANCHO*ALTO))
    img3 = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, ANCHO*ALTO))
    img2 = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, ANCHO*ALTO))
    img4 = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, ANCHO*ALTO))
    X_index = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, 1))
    Y = np.zeros((contador_positivo + contador_negativo, 1))
    
    sampleIndex = 0
    # leer todas las imágenes, convertir a flotantes, dividir por 255 (conduce al rango de grises 0..1), remodelar en un vector de fila
     # escriba la clase 0 para muestras positivas y 1 para muestras negativas   
    sampleIndex = leer_conjunto_imagenes(positiveImageFiles, path_imagenes_positivas_entrenamiento, img1, img3, img2, img4, X_index, Y, sampleIndex, 0)
    print('positive data loaded.')
    
    sampleIndex += leer_conjunto_imagenes(negativeImageFiles, path_imagenes_negativas_entrenamiento, img1, img3, img2, img4, X_index, Y, sampleIndex, 1)
    print('negative data loaded.')

    print('Total Samples Loaded: ', sampleIndex)
    print(img1)
    print(img3)
    print(Y)
    
    return img1, img3, img2, img4, X_index, Y, contador_imagenes_totales
```

this is the function where the images are read and decomposed into the arrays that I need

```py
img1_train_x,img2_train_x,img3_train_x,img4_train_x,Y_train,img1_test_x,img2_test_x,img3_test_x,img4_test_x,Y_test = trainTestSplit(img1, img2, img3, img4, X_index, Y, imageCount)
    
    model = entrenar_modelo_CNN(img1_train_x,img2_train_x,img3_train_x,img4_train_x,Y_train,
             img1_test_x,img2_test_x,img3_test_x,img4_test_x,Y_test, epocas)
```

Finally, this is the function that trains my model, as parameters it receives the arrays already processed and ordered corresponding to the images, the problem is that since the memory is full, how can I go through them little by little or read them according to the needs to?

```py
def entrenar_modelo_CNN(img1_train_x,img2_train_x,img3_train_x,img4_train_x,y_train,
             img1_test_x,img2_test_x,img3_test_x,img4_test_x,y_test, epocas):

    batch_size = 32 # en cada iteración, consideramos 32 ejemplos de entrenamiento a la vez
    num_train, height, width, depth = img1_train_x.shape
    numero_de_clases = len(np.unique(y_train))
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, numero_de_clases) # Codificar las etiquetas en caliente
    Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, numero_de_clases) # Codifica las etiquetas en caliente

    checkPointFolder = 'checkPoint'
    checkpoint_name = checkPointFolder + '/Weights-{epoch:03d}--{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5' 
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    
    if not os.path.exists(checkPointFolder):
        os.makedirs(checkPointFolder)
        
    model = createModel(height, width, depth, numero_de_clases)

    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', # usando la función de pérdida de entropía cruzada
                  optimizer='adam', # usando el optimizador de Adam
                  metrics=['accuracy']) # reportando la precisión


    model.fit([img1_train_x,img2_train_x,img3_train_x,img4_train_x], Y_train,# Entrene al modelo usando el conjunto de entrenamiento ...
              batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epocas,
              verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=callbacks_list) # ... reteniendo el 10% de los datos para su validación
    score, acc = model.evaluate([img1_test_x,img2_test_x,img3_test_x,img4_test_x], Y_test, verbose=1)  # ¡Evalúe el modelo entrenado en el equipo de prueba!

    model.save('moirePattern3CNN_.h5')
    
    return model
```

Comment: Could you please provide some of the code you used?

Comment: of course, at one point I edit the question and add part of the code

Comment: done, code added @Juicestus